# Return all arrays inside foreach loop

Tags: php

How to return all array values inside foreach loop. Return is working fine and no error but is only one record. If i have 10 records in database, It supposed to be all records. What did i missed this code? thanks for your help.

PHP

```
function myfunction(){
    $query ="SELECT * from tbl_data";
    $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $value) {

        //custom value
        $customval = 1;

        $array = array([
            "ID"                => $value['ID'],
            "name"              => $value['name'],
            "staus"             => $value['status'],
            "customval"         => $customval,
        ]);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: You need to insert/append the records on each iteration. What you are doing is just updating the values with teh current step, so it will give you the last record. You need to take the record, and push it inside an array on each iteration. `$array[] = `

Comment: can you give me an example just like above so i have an idea. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently actually just overwriting $array, you need to push the new data to it instead.

```
$array = array();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $value) {

    //custom value
    $customval = 1;

    $array[] = [
        "ID"                => $value['ID'],
        "name"              => $value['name'],
        "staus"             => $value['status'],
        "customval"         => $customval,
    ];
}

return $myArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning $array on every iteration, overwriting the previous value.

Maybe you want to create an array of arrays:

```
    $array = array();
    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $value) {
       //custom value
       $customval = 1;

       array_push($array, array([
          "ID"                => $value['ID'],
          "name"              => $value['name'],
          "staus"             => $value['status'],
          "customval"         => $customval,
       ]));
    }
    return $array;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are only getting one value returned because you are overwriting the value of the array each time.

You need to push the new values each loop iteration.

```
$myArray = array();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $value) {

    //custom value
    $customval = 1;

    array_push($myArray, array([
        "ID"                => $value['ID'],
        "name"              => $value['name'],
        "staus"             => $value['status'],
        "customval"         => $customval,
    ]));
}

return $myArray;
```

This will return an array of arrays.

Comment: This isn't actually valid PHP

Comment: @Nick what exactly isn't valid?

Comment: im assuming you got mixed up with another language, `.` notation has different meaning in PHP

Comment: Lol that was me using JS all day showing..There fixed,